# Integrating composer repository into php file

Tags: php, composer-php, json-rpc

I am trying to use this php wrapper for multichain's json rpc api. I have this php file on a VPS with multichain installed: https://github.com/Kunstmaan/libphp-multichain in a php file. However I am not correctly integrating it and would appreciate any help!

```
<?php
    require_once '../libphp-multichain/src/be/MultichainClient.php';
    require_once '../libphp-multichain/src/be/MultichainHelper.php';
    $client = MultichainClient("multichainrpc","{multichainpwd}",{host_address},{port},3);
    $getinfo = $client->setDebug(true)->getInfo();
    print_r($client);
    print_r($getinfo);
?>
```

The error I see in apache error log is:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../libphp-multichain/src/be/MultichainClient.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/new.php on line 3

Comment: Make sure your `path/to/MutichainClient.php` is correct. `../` means one directory above the file that is running the `require_once` command. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using the wrong path. Try this:

```
require_once '../libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainClient.php';
require_once '../libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainHelper.php';
```